# how to create gridView like this?

Tags: flutter

[image]

```
class ProductListView extends StatelessWidget {
  const ProductListView({Key? key,required this.list}) : super(key: key);

  final List<Product> list;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return GridView.builder(
      physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: deviceSize.width * 0.07,right: deviceSize.width * 0.07,),
      itemCount: 10,
      gridDelegate:  SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        childAspectRatio: 0.66,
        //mainAxisExtent:  deviceSize.height * 0.2824,
        mainAxisSpacing: deviceSize.height * 0.035,
        crossAxisSpacing: deviceSize.width * 0.08
      ),

      itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return  ProductItem(
                    product: Product(id:list[index].id,
                    title: list[index].title,
                    price: list[index].price,
                    description: list[index].description,
                    category: list[index].category,
                    image: list[index].image,),
                    index: index,
        );

      },

    );
  }
}
```

how to set gridTile like this

Comment: Check out this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view

Comment: ok thanx but i already checked this

Answer (score 1):

Use flutter's [Stggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view)

Add Dependencies:

```
flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.3.3
transparent_image: ^1.0.0
```

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> imageList = [
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/03/15/09/49/girl-4056684_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/15/16/25/clock-5834193__340.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/09/18/19/31/laptop-5582775_960_720.jpg',
    'https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/woman-kayaking-in-fjord-in-norway-picture-id1059380230?b=1&k=6&m=1059380230&s=170667a&w=0&h=kA_A_XrhZJjw2bo5jIJ7089-VktFK0h0I4OWDqaac0c=',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/11/05/00/53/cellular-4602489_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/12/10/29/christmas-2059698_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/01/29/17/09/snowboard-4803050_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/02/06/20/01/university-library-4825366_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/11/22/17/28/cat-5767334_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/13/16/22/snow-5828736_960_720.jpg',
    'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/12/09/09/27/women-5816861_960_720.jpg',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white24,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Flutter Staggered GridView Demo"),
          centerTitle: true,
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        ),
        body: Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
          child:  StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 10,
              mainAxisSpacing: 12,
              itemCount: imageList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(15))
                  ),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(15)),
                    child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                      placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                      image: imageList[index],fit: BoxFit.cover,),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (index) {
                return StaggeredTile.count(1, index.isEven ? 1.2 : 1.8);
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: its is old example and now many property changed